# 'init()' is deprecated: init() will be removed in Swift 3. Use `nil`

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, audiounit, opaque-pointers

I was using this code.

```
var audioUnit:AudioUnit = AudioUnit()
```

But in Xcode 7.3 (Swift 2.2) I am getting this warning. Any idea why? And how can I get rid of that?

N.B. Is I use `nil` then my program crashes.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AudioUnit` is a typealias of `AudioComponentInstance` which itself is a typealias of `COpaquePointer`.  [Initializing pointers will be removed with Swift 3.0](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md), just set the variable to `nil`.

`nil` and `AudioUnit()` should do the same thing.  If your program is crashing with `nil`, you probably have a bug somewhere else.

[image: Xcode Playground]

Comment: @JarrodSmith please make sure when you edit someone else's answer you use a valid link.  I've made an edit which corrected your invalid hyperlink.